# Here Waypoint Sequencing API Doesn't Honor Delivery Windows

Tags: here-api, waypoint

I am experimenting with the HERE Waypoint Sequencing API using the new JSON request format, and it doesn't seem to take into account delivery windows specified in the times array within the plan object.  I went back to the example provided in the documentation and found that the same thing was happening:  Arrival and departure times are far from the specified delivery windows.

In my Example, Customer 1 has times:

```
"times": [["2020-07-04T08:00:00Z","2020-07-04T10:00:00Z"],["2020-07-04T16:00:00Z","2020-07-04T18:00:00Z"]]
```

However, the solution contains:

```
      "time": {
        "arrival": "2020-07-04T00:30:00.000+0000",
        "departure": "2020-07-04T00:33:00.000+0000"
      }
```

Which isn't even close.

Endpoint:  https://wps.hereapi.com/v8/findsequence

Request:

```
{
  "configuration": {
    "optimizations": {
      "traffic": "liveOrHistorical",
      "waitingTime": {
        "bufferTime": 15,
        "reduce": false
      }
    }
  },
  "fleet": {
    "profiles": [{"type":"car","name":"normal_car"}],
    "types": [
      {
        "amount": 1,
        "capacity": [10,5],
        "costs": {
          "distance": 0.0001,
          "fixed": 22,
          "time": 0.0048
        },
        "id": "string",
        "limits": {
          "maxDistance": 20000,
          "shiftTime": 21600
        },
        "profile": "normal_car",
        "shifts": [
          {
            "breaks": [
              {
                "duration": 180,
                "location": {
                  "lat": 52.53088,
                  "lng": 13.38471
                },
                "times": [["2020-07-04T08:00:00Z","2020-07-04T10:00:00Z"],["2020-07-04T16:00:00Z","2020-07-04T18:00:00Z"]]
              }
            ],
            "end": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              },
              "time": "2020-07-04T23:30:00Z"

            },
            "start": {
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              },
              "time":  "2020-07-04T00:30:00Z"
            }
          }
        ],
        "skills": ["fridge"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
  "plan": {
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": "string",
        "places": {
          "deliveries": [
            {
              "demand": [10,5],
              "duration": 180,
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.38471
              },
              "tag": "Customer 1",
              "times": [["2020-07-04T08:00:00Z","2020-07-04T10:00:00Z"],["2020-07-04T16:00:00Z","2020-07-04T18:00:00Z"]]
            },
            {
              "demand": [10,5],
              "duration": 180,
              "location": {
                "lat": 53.53088,
                "lng": 14.98471
              },
              "tag": "Customer 2",
              "times": [["2020-07-04T08:00:00Z","2020-07-04T10:00:00Z"],["2020-07-04T16:00:00Z","2020-07-04T18:00:00Z"]]
            }
          ],
          "pickups": [
            {
              "demand": [10,5],
              "duration": 180,
              "location": {
                "lat": 52.53088,
                "lng": 13.98471
              },
              "tag": "some_tag",
              "times": [["2020-07-04T08:00:00Z","2020-07-04T10:00:00Z"],["2020-07-04T16:00:00Z","2020-07-04T18:00:00Z"]]
            }
          ]
        },
        "skills": ["fridge"]
      }
    ],
    "relations": [
      {
        "jobs": [
          "string"
        ],
        "type": "flexible",
        "vehicleId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "problemId": "7f3423c2-784a-4983-b472-e14107d5a54a",
  "statistic": {
    "cost": null,
    "distance": 441655,
    "duration": 20127,
    "times": {
      "break": 0,
      "driving": 19587,
      "serving": 540,
      "waiting": 0
    }
  },
  "tours": [
    {
      "vehicleId": "string",
      "typeId": null,
      "stops": [
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 52.53088,
            "lng": 13.38471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": null,
            "departure": "2020-07-04T00:30:00.000+0000"
          },
          "load": [
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "departure",
              "jobTag": "departure",
              "type": null,
              "location": null,
              "time": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 52.53088,
            "lng": 13.38471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": "2020-07-04T00:30:00.000+0000",
            "departure": "2020-07-04T00:33:00.000+0000"
          },
          "load": [
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "Customer 1",
              "jobTag": "Customer 1",
              "type": null,
              "location": null,
              "time": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 52.53088,
            "lng": 13.98471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": "2020-07-04T01:34:05.000+0000",
            "departure": "2020-07-04T01:37:05.000+0000"
          },
          "load": [
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "some_tag",
              "jobTag": "some_tag",
              "type": null,
              "location": null,
              "time": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 53.53088,
            "lng": 14.98471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": "2020-07-04T03:53:37.000+0000",
            "departure": "2020-07-04T03:56:37.000+0000"
          },
          "load": [
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "Customer 2",
              "jobTag": "Customer 2",
              "type": null,
              "location": null,
              "time": null
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "location": {
            "lat": 52.53088,
            "lng": 13.38471
          },
          "time": {
            "arrival": "2020-07-04T06:05:27.000+0000",
            "departure": null
          },
          "load": [
          ],
          "activities": [
            {
              "jobId": "arrival",
              "jobTag": "arrival",
              "type": null,
              "location": null,
              "time": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "statistic": {
        "cost": null,
        "distance": 441655,
        "duration": 20127,
        "times": {
          "break": 0,
          "driving": 19587,
          "serving": 540,
          "waiting": 0
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "unassigned": null
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: ...<Crickets>...

Comment: I just submitted the request again - if this is a bug it's still not fixed.

Comment: Have you managed to overcome this?

Comment: @Riwen - No activity on this at all.  The last time I looked the documentation warned that v8 was not stable.  The v2 API works, it's just that the interface isn't as modern.